# upload multiple images to facebook using SLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, image-uploading, slrequest

I have 2 ways for share images to Facebook.

The SDK Way (work perfect):

```
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *uploadImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UIImage *image in images) {
        FBSDKSharePhoto *sharePhoto = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
        sharePhoto.caption = title;
        sharePhoto.image = image;

        [uploadImages addObject:sharePhoto];
    }
    content.photos = [NSArray arrayWithArray:uploadImages];

    [FBSDKShareAPI shareWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

and SLRequest way (only send 1 image):

```
+ (void)uploadPhotoToFacebook:(NSMutableArray *)imagesData imageTitle:(NSString *)title account:(ACAccount*)account completionBlock:(shareSocialResponse)completion
{
    SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                              URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"]
                                                       parameters:@{@"message": title}];

    for (NSData *imageData in imagesData) {
        [facebookRequest addMultipartData:imageData
                                 withName:@"source"
                                     type:@"multipart/form-data"
                                 filename:@"photo!"];
    }
    NSLog(@"facebookRequest %@",facebookRequest);
    facebookRequest.account = account;
    [facebookRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);

        } else {
            NSDictionary *returnedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            NSLog(@"returnedData: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

            if ([urlResponse statusCode] != 200) {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSString *errorMessage = @"We could not process your request now";
                    if ([returnedData valueForKeyPath:@"error.message"] != nil) {
                        errorMessage = [returnedData valueForKeyPath:@"error.message"];
                    }
                    completion(NO, errorMessage);
                });
            } else {
                completion(YES, @"Your clip was posted!");
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

> I believed that if each data sent in a multipart might work, but no.

Anyone have any idea how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some article in the facebook docs that might help you.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

So, in your case you will need to send a field called `batch` in your request and each file must be attached with a unique name so it won't be rewrite by another.

The content of `batch` field will be a json in which you will specify the endpoint of your request, something like this(minified btw):

```
[
  {
    "method": "POST",
    "relative_url": "me/photos",
    "body": "message=labrys",
    "attached_files": "file1"
  },
  {
    "method": "POST",
    "relative_url": "me/photos",
    "body": "message=circle",
    "attached_files": "file2"
  }
]
```

I tried it with postman, the settings for that request should look like this:

[image]

Sorry for not posting code, I'm not versed in objective C but I hope you get the idea of this.